# R - Passing a vector of values to a function (apply confusion)

Tags: r, function, for-loop, apply

I want to send values from a vector to a function that, depending on those values, modifies a matrix in a particular way. I am sure this must be easy and I am missing something.

Here is my code:

```
lima <- matrix(0,nrow=4,ncol=4)

foo <- function(i,lima) {
  if (i == 1) {
    lima[1,3] = 1
  } else if (i==2) {
    lima[2,4] = 2
  } else if (i==3) {
    lima[2,3] = 3
  } else if (i==4) {
    lima[4,4] = 4
  }
  return(lima)
}
```

OK. I can do the next step with a `for` loop:

```
x <- 1:4
for (i in x) {
  lima <- foo(i, lima)
}
```

And this seems to work:

```
> lima
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    3    2
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4
>
```

But how can I do this without the `for` loop? I thought one of the `apply` family might do the trick, but that seems like a non-standard application and anyway I can't get it to work.

Help? And thanks!

Comment: Could you expand what `foo` should do? For now `foo(1, lima) == foo(2, lima)` up to `4`...

Comment: `sapply(x, function(x) lima <<- foo(x, lima))` ... but I think your overall code could be restructured to make it more vectorized.

Comment: Or change your `if`s to be like `if (1 %in% i)`, `else if (2 %in% i)`, etc.

Comment: @ThomasGuillerme -- `foo` will increment an element of the `lima` matrix. More detail: I have a 40k line binary matrix indicating the presence (1) or absence (0) of 6 different features. `foo` will translate that binary matrix into a matrix that sums features based on certain rules. That's `lima`. (The rules are a little involved; essentially, `lima` is a 2D matrix where rows and columns represent nodes and the elements represent line widths connecting those nodes. That's probably more detail than you need!)

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen and @Marius -- right. It's that more vectorized approach that I am after. (I couldn't get the `sapply` code to work, but I will try again.) Regarding the `if`s, I might try to replace them with `cases` from `memisc`, but I wanted to conquer the `for` loop problem first...